# Update self in an inherited class data structure

Tags: python, class, inheritance, self

I want to inherit and modify Python list class to add extra functionality - i.e. a method that removes all instances of an element:

```
class NewList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__list__ = self

    def rm_all(self, qw):
        rm = [x for x in self if x != qw]
        return rm
```

So, if I do:

```
l = NewList([1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2])`
print(l.rm_all(1))
```

Output is:

```
[2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2]
```

However, the list remains intact (I need to call `l = l.rm_all(1)` to update). Whereas, in Python lists if I use `l.remove(2)` the list gets updated automatically.

How can I incorporate this kind of functionality in my new inherited class - i.e. when I type `l.rm_all(1)` the list automatically updates?

I assume I need to reassign *`self`* but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a meta class of `list`, you could try changing the values of `self` with the following:

```
class NewList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__list__ = self

    def rm_all(self, qw):
        self[:] = [x for x in self if x != qw]

l = NewList([1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2])
l.rm_all(1)
print(l)
```